# How can I reference a partial form another folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

/views/category/_blah.html.erb
/views/users/show.html.erb

Inside of show, I want to render the partial _blah but I am getting an error as it cant' find it.

Answer (score 10):

try using

```
<%= render :partial => "category/blah" %>
```

inside your view.

(This is definitely good coding practice, as you'll find it in the ["Rendering Partial Collections"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#rendering-partial-collections) page in the first Rails Guide.)